# How do you say Difference between?

Tags: translation

How do you say the **difference** in this context: the difference between 4 and 6 is 2. It is 区别?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `difference` should be translated as 差額 or simply 差.

> 四和六的差額為二

But if I have the freedom to not translate `difference` as noun but verb, I would simply say

> 四和六相差二

Comment: Just want to add that 差额 is usually used for money figure. It's proper but less common for pure number.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 'difference' is 差额.

4和6之间的差额是2.